# Change Phoenix framework process user with setgid and setuid after deploy?

Tags: deployment, elixir, phoenix-framework

We've finished our first phoenix application for internal company use and it is time now to deploy it. It will be hidden under Apache server (yep, nginx is not available as an option), and according to PCI DSS standard it should be run under readonly user. Node.js devs use some functions [like this](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_setegid_id) in their startup configs to change user from 'deployer' which can write to filesystem to 'runner' (readonly user) which just read the code.

So, when my app is starting up after deploy, user should be dynamically changed from 'deploy' to 'runner'. What is the best way to do it? BTW, I'm not completely understood how Cowboy works, but I guess it just runs in the background like unicorn or puma?

Comment: Why not just use init / upstart scripts (or anything else that monitors at the OS level) and just start the application using the proper user to begin with?

Comment: @JustinWood, well, now app will be running under centos and systemd. Later it might be moved to ubuntu. The answer is portability. Ruby web-servers, JS web-servers use this approaches, you start them under root, and after, they switch to another user.